# How to hide a apex:pageBlockSectionItem by Javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I'm **hiding** a field row (**apex:pageBlockSectionItem**) using the next code:

VF:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
  <apex:outputLabel value="My nice field" for="myField"/>
  <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!dummy}" id="myField" styleClass="myField"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.myField').closest('tr').hide()
```

I dont like the idea of get the block container using the html tag name (tr). I think that if salesforce changed the implementation of apex:pageBlockSectionItem component for any device, this code wouldn't work.

There is a better way to address this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you are using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). This is a theory which may or may not work, but what about wrapping the [apex:pageBlockSectionItem](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_pageBlockSectionItem.htm) with an [apex:outputPanel](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputPanel.htm). You can then add a `styleClass` to the apex:outputPanel and use that to be referenced in the Javascript. See below:

```
<apex:outputPanel styleClass="fieldToHide">
  <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:outputLabel value="My nice field" for="myField"/>
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!dummy}" id="myField" styleClass="myField"/>
  </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

---

```
$('.fieldToHide').hide();
```

---

If you aren't using jQuery (or maybe you simply don't want to do that), you can always use the rendered attribute on the apex:pageBlockSectionItem with an [apex:actionSupport](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm).

Comment: Unfortunately, pageBlockSectionItem ID doesn't render a  html node using that ID. Instead of this, the Id attribute is only useful by {$Component...}. Take a look of the official doc  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm

Comment: Ah, you are correct. Interesting. I have an idea, I will update my response.

Comment: Now sounds better. I'll wait to see if other cleaver idea appear before accept your response. Thx

Comment: The $Component var has issues when dealing with jQuery.  Also, just plain issues.

jQuery supports partial selectors, however, so you can find an element with a known ID like so:

accountDiv = j$(id*=idname);

Answer (score 2):

Using the dataStyleClass and labelStyleClass attributes on the PageBlockSectionItem would allow you to hide both the label and the data cells rendered by the item. `hidden` is a native page style definition.

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="hidden niceField" labelStyleClass="hidden niceField" >
    <apex:outputLabel value="My nice field" for="myField"/>
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!dummy}" id="myField" styleClass="myField"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

At this point you still have a visible `tr` which has no visible `td` children.

You can then target them using the secondary class to show them again.

- `$('.niceField').show();`
- `$('.niceField').removeClass('hidden');`

This may not be exactly what you're looking for since it hides the cells but leaves the row, but it's worth noting just the same.

Answer (score 1):

Set a `dataStyleClass` on the `apex:pageBlockSectionItem`.

You write the following visualforce:

```
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="page-block-section-item">
            <apex:outputLabel value="My nice field" for="myField"/>
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!dummy}" id="myField" styleClass="myField"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

It renders the following html:

```
<div class="pbSubsection">
    <table class="detailList" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="labelCol  first  last ">
                    <label for="...:myField">
                        My nice field
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="dataCol  first  last page-block-section-item">
                    <input id="...:myField" type="checkbox" 
                           name="...:myField" class="myField">
                </td>
                <td class="labelCol empty">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="dataCol empty">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

You can hide the page block section item just by selecting the `<td>` tag by class then using the `parent` method.

```
$('td.page-block-section-item').parent().hide();
```

Comment: Thanks phil *but* If I had more than one element into the  blocksection (in my sample are two), this wouldn't work. I need to hide from <td> level.

Comment: Edited to make it more accurate to the original question.