# In Visualforce, make a decision based on the state of a component

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

In the following scenario, how can I work out if something has happened because the user interacted with `<c:myComponent>` so that in my page I can decide whether to render `Hello World!`?

```
<apex:page>
  <c:myComponent>
  <apex:outputPanel rendered="?">
    Hello World!
  </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

I need to replace the `?` in rendered with something that works!

I want something like `{!myComponent.controller.hasDoneStuff}` or `<c:myComponent var="doneStuff" /> ... rendered="{!doneStuff}"`

Can this be done?

Comment: Good solution described here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103363/how-to-get-in-a-visualforce-page-controller-a-value-from-a-custom-component-cont

Comment: Thanks, it is a good solution, but so far I don't need to pass anything to the method I'm calling.  I could use that solution if it turns out to be the only way, but it will be cleaner if I can just do it using visualforce markup.

Comment: You don't need to pass anything to the method. Only to the component. An alternative would be to use javascript inside the Component to change the visibility parameters of the outputpanel, but that would go completely around VisualForce standards. Like here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10028/how-to-hide-a-apexpageblocksectionitem-by-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer provided by [guy](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2279/guy) [to here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103363/how-to-get-in-a-visualforce-page-controller-a-value-from-a-custom-component-cont) is a good lightweight solution, there is a more in depth description of [Controller Component Communication](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Controller_Component_Communication) at developerforce which gives me the option to have my page controller and component controller collaborate.